# why we can call getActivity() in onCreateView which run before onActivityCreated?

Tags: android, fragment, lifecycle

I really get confused with `Fragment` [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating), especially for the time to call `getActivity()`. Sometimes you cannot get `Activity` by `getActivity()`. And it always caused some puzzling bugs.
Thank you for anyone can solve the puzzle.

Comment: Relevant code example please!

Comment: From the [Fragments documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html): `Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can call getActivity(). However, be careful to call getActivity() only when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment is not yet attached, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle, getActivity() will return null.`. So it should be called from `onAttach`.

Comment: @EricMartinez I don't think that's a correct interpretation of the documentation. My understanding is that since the fragment is associated with the activity when onAttach() is called, then it must also be available for the following lifecycle methods like onCreate() and onCreateView(), even though it is confusing that they are called before onActivityCreated(). Anyway, I don't recall ever getting null when calling getActivity() in onCreateView(), and all the Android apps I've written have done that.

Answer (score 14):

`getActivity()` can be null while your fragment is in process of preparation and about to be ready.

The fragment life cycle is bound to callback methods. These method will be called somewhere in time while fragment is preparing.

- [Fragment.onActivityCreated(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) is the place when the fragment activity will not be null, i.e. `getActivity()` will be a valid instance. It happens after `onCreateView()` though

Your safest bet for activity existence is:

- [Fragment.onViewCreated(View, Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29)
- [Fragment.onStart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onStart())

Comment: What if I need an activity to create an adapter in onCreate?

Comment: I've got 'getActivity() == null' in 'Fragment.onViewCreated(View, Bundle)' few times, so it's not safe, you must always check if getActivity() is not null in 'onCreateView()', 'onViewCreated()' and even 'onResume()'

Comment: We don't bet on things. Either it's supposed to be a valid Activity in onAttach() or it's not. Why is there not a clear answer to the use of getActivity()?

Comment: @SteveM Thumbs for we dont bet on things :)

Comment: Guesstimation sucks. You can get the activity onAttach, as per the Android Studio generated template code for fragment/activity communication.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the current documentation (Dec 2018)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle), it shows that `onAttach()` is called right at the beginning before `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`. It should be safe to `getActivity()` in these methods.

[image: Fragment lifecycle]

---

In the [Support v4 Fragment documentation for `onActivityCreated()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) it says that this method is:

> Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated.

The important part here is that the "activity has been created" i.e. `Activity.onCreate()` has finished executing. Before this point we are still within that method.

This can be confirmed by looking at [the `FragmentActivity.onCreate()` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/cef09fe/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#312) you can follow the process of fragments being attached to the activity at the start of the method, then the fragment state being restored etc etc. So the activity should be valid in all those places, but technically it has not finished with the whole create process.