# android - Start new activity from fragment, apk built but crashes on device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm trying to start new activity from fragment and here is my code:

```
public class HomePage extends Fragment {

View rootview;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage_layout, container, false);

    Button newPage = (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.view_our_products);
    newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductsOverview.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootview;
}
}
```

There are no errors reflected by Android studio. But after I build the apk and click on this button it crashes and says "Unfortunately Sample App has stopped".

Comment: Please add the logcat output showing the error as well as your layout-file.

Comment: can u please post your logcat?

Comment: `getActivity()` probably returns null. Please post the stacktrace from logcat

Comment: And also the OnCreateMethod fo the ProductsOverview activity (And don't forget to add the activity on manifest)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236451/why-we-can-call-getactivity-in-oncreateview-which-run-before-onactivitycreated

Comment: Logcat says - E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.app.run.sampleapp/com.app.run.sampleapp.ProductsOverview}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? This is a fragment so we can't add it to androidmanifest.

Comment: You need to add the target Activity to the manifest, not the fragment where you are launching it.

Comment: @user2672112. If `ProductsOverview` is a Fragment, you can't add it to the manifest indeed, but you can't start it like an activity either. You need to build an activity that contains `ProductsOverview` and start that activity

Answer (score 0):

Your ProductsOverview.class is an fragment not an Activity so make that as a Activity by ProductOverview extends AppCompatActivity.

Hope this will help you